# Running npm run compile:sass returns error: npm ERR! missing script: compile:sass

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, sass

The sass folders and files are in the correct place. What is wrong?

I have the package.json which I created, with this code in there.

```js
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "starter file",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
  },
  "author": "Nez",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  }
}
```

As you can see the script is called compile sass when I try to run it it keeps giving the error
npm ERR! missing script: compile:sass

I have the sass compiler installed already as a dev dependency

Comment: How are you running that command? Did you navigate to the folder that contains the above package.json? The error points to a) npm finding a package.json file in the current dir but b) the file not containing `compile:sass` in its scripts.

Comment: yes I'm in the folder and I wrote "npm run compile:sass" in the terminal.

Comment: I tried the same thing and it worked fine for me. Not sure how to help you since I can't reproduce the error (unless I remove the script from package.json).

Comment: What happens if you run the script directly? `npx node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w`

Comment: This is what I get when I run it directly.
`$ npx node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w
An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'sass/main.scss' `

Comment: Did you checked your file path?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to package.json
2. Add below lines

```json
"scripts": {
  "sass": "sass sass/main.scss css/style.css",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

3. For compilation use command:

```bash
npm run sass
```

Note: I have used **main.scss** as source file name

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen as well. The only way I could fix it was to move my files out of my dropbox folder on an external hard drive and move them to my main computers' hard drive. I think it has something to do with Dropbox, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

One of your sass files has a syntax error

eg.
file 1 has

- background: **%pink**

the **%pink** value is undefined you should check your files if *%pink** is implemented

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything until I simply saved the project files within my code editor and then all of a sudden it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code all you need to do is add `npx` before your `node`

I.e. `npx node...`

Then go to your terminal to that directory and run this command `npm run compile:sass`

Hope this works...because it worked for me will work for you too

Comment: Thanks for the answer Agney, however to make this more useful to the OP it'd be worth explaining exactly why `npx` helps and what it does, additionally how it solves the problem for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your file path

Answer (score 0):

After 3 years!
for me it's solved by rewriting the package.json "scripts" line :

```
"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
```